# Controller side column binding for Telerik MVC Grid

Tags: asp.net-mvc, telerik, telerik-mvc

I have a partial view that uses a Telerik MVC Grid, and it has column binding code as follows (very partial view):

```
.Columns(column =>
{
    column.Bound(model => model.PlannedFinishDate).Title("Planned Date").Format("{0:dd/MM/yyyy}").Width(83);
    column.Bound(model => model.Province).Width(70);
    if (Roles.IsUserInRole("Controller") == true)
    {
        column.Bound(model => model.InstallerName).Width(85);
        column.Bound(model => model.InstallerAccepted).Title("Accepted").Width(45);
        column.Bound(model => model.KitShippedDescription).Width(70);
    }
// etc. etc.
```

Now I need to write a controller action to export the same data as rendered in the grid to Excel, and I need the same role based column inclusion/exclusion.  I don't want to duplicate the role checking logic, so I'm looking for a way to generate the data used here for column binding in the controller, pass it with the ViewData, and use it in the view to dynamically bind the columns.

Comment: Let me get this straightened: you want the user be able to download the exact same HTML grid as an Excel spreadsheet by clicking on some link? Or save to an Excel file on the server?

Comment: I want the user to be able to click on a link and download a spreadsheet generated on the server.  I can't just let the user dpownload the grid because it's paged, and the spreadhseet must contain all pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps [this](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc-beta/grid/columnsettings) example would help. There is a disclaimer though - this is still in beta and the final API will change from

```
.Columns((IEnumerable<GridColumnSettings<T>>)ViewData["Columns"])
```

to

```
.Columns(columns => columns.LoadSettings((IEnumerable<GridColumnSettings<T>>)ViewData["Columns"]))
```

Comment: I can't find the GridColumnSettings type anywhere.

Comment: It looks like *GridColumnSettings* is new to Q2, still in beta, so I won't be allowed to use it in a production app.

Comment: That's great @korchev.  It's a great product and I look foward to beign able to use Q2.